# use of require_auth2

Tags: authorization

I'm interested in checking whether a specific permissions has been passed to a method invocation (as opposed to `active`) and have read one can use the `require_auth2` method but when I try it I get the following error:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'require_auth2'; did you mean 'eosio::internal_use_do_not_use::require_auth2'?

so clearly this is internal and not meant to be used.  how do I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ API is wrapped differently.

```
inline void require_auth( const permission_level& level ) {
  internal_use_do_not_use::require_auth2( level.actor.value, level.permission.value );
}

// how to use
require_auth(permission_level("eosio"_n, "vote"_n));
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `permission_level{}`?

Comment: @ekkis Both are allowed.
https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/a6b8d3fc289d46f4612588cdd7223a3d549238f6/libraries/eosiolib/contracts/eosio/action.hpp#L187